# What am I to do now I've gotten all the rewards?

Tags: support, unicorns

I've spent the last hour repeatedly clicking my mouse to mine all the coins. I have now opened all of the unicorn rewards. What am I to do with my life now? I am getting unicorn withdrawal symptoms. Please help.

Comment: Closing as Gen Ref. See the FAQ.

Comment: Surely you've got something else on your bucket list...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's going to be OK. Put on some Allman Brothers, then lie on the floor, and just stare at the ceiling for a while. Enjoy the ride while it lasts.